# How to create a class with multiple (interchangable) behaviours

Tags: java, oop

I am pretty new to Java and I have been struggling with the following for quite a while now.

I have this class 'Human' in my project, and as a part of my model, I would like my humans to be able to specialise and thus having new behaviours. For example, I could have a human that would start as 'Civil' but later on could change into a 'Soldier' and learn new behaviour.

I used to do this in Smalltalk by adding an instance variable to my 'Human' class, that would point to an instance of 'Civil', so that way I could point that to a new instance of 'Soldier' later on in the game, but now that in Java I am restricted to types, I am not sure how to tackle it (I don't think adding one instance variable for each possible type can be a possible solution, but I might be wrong).

So, how would you model this? Any hint on how I can tackle this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can a Humna be more than one of these types? and what exactly in Smalltalk do you mean

Answer (score 3):

You could use Composition instead of inheritance. So, a Human would have a variable inside it that represents its behaviour. You could call it HumanBehaviour. Extend HumanBehaviour and create a SoldierBehaviour and a CivilBehaviour. So, you can change your instance behaviour at any time. just do a myHuman.setBehaviour(new SoldierBehaviour()) or a myHuman.setBehaviour(new CivilBehaviour());

Answer (score 2):

```
class Human {
    Job job = new Civil();
}

interface Job {
    void work();
}

class Civil implements Job {
    void work() {
        cutDownTrees();
    }
}

class Soldier implemets Job {
    void work() {
        lookForEnemies();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need a [Strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

In your case you should create a `Behaviour` interface, implemented by classes `Civil` and `Soldier`:

```
public interface Behavior {
  void doSmthg();
}

public class Civil implements Behavior {
  void doSmthg(){ /* do it like a civil! */ }
}

public class Soldier implements Behavior {
  void doSmthg(){ /* do it like a soldier! */ }
}

public class Human {

  private Behavior behavior = new Civil();

  public void setBehavior(Behavior b) {
    this.behavior = b;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! this seems to be the solution that adapts the most to my needs (others were great too) It seems I lacked knowledge on Strategy design pattern, great article. I have one doubt still. What if I would like to ADD behaviour to the Human, (for example the ability to use weapons in case it turned into a soldier) and that this behaviour wasn't available for Civils? I can think of turnarounds such as implementing dummy behaviours for civils, but perhaps that's not the best solution?

Comment: You can also check the Decorator design pattern. In you case, isn't a Soldier just a Human decorated with a uniform and a weapon?

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns come handy in this situation.

You are looking for dynamic extension of the object, Decorator pattern helps you deal with it. Other simple way of doing this is to do by strategy pattern, where soldier will be a strategy, civil will be a strategy, you add it to the person object, now this person will become soldier or civil etc.,